# Self-invocation shouldn't be adviced but it does

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, aop

I'm getting a weird behavior by Spring AOP AspectJ: self-invocation shouldn't be adviced, but in my application it does. From [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies):

> However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the
>   SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may make
>   on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be invoked
>   against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has important
>   implications. **It means that self-invocation is not going to result in
>   the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to
>   execute.**

But in my simple application, composed by:

a TestAspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.mypackage.TestService.method(..))")
    public void participateAroundPointcut(){}

    @Around("participateAroundPointcut()")
    public void testAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        logger.debug("Pre-execution;");

        joinPoint.proceed();

        logger.debug("Post-execution");
    }

}
```

a TestService:

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class);

    public void method(){
        logger.debug("Executing method();");
    }

    public void service(){
        logger.debug("Executing service();");
        this.method();
    }
}
```

and a configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mypackage" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy  proxy-target-class="true" />
<bean id="testAspect" class="org.mypackage.aop.aspects.TestAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"/>
```

I get the self-invocation adviced:

```
DEBUG: org.mypackage.TestService - Executing service();
DEBUG: org.mypackage.aop.aspects.TestAspect - Pre-execution;
DEBUG: org.mypackage.TestService - Executing method();
DEBUG: org.mypackage.aop.aspects.TestAspect - Post-execution
```

I can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: IMO it's important to include full source and information; which annotations are being used matters, the IDE matters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely the IDE - if you are using Eclipse with AspectJ enabled for your project, the AspectJ plugin will weave your target classes. Try to run your test outside of the IDE (if it is maven project, you can run `mvn clean test`) and you should then see the expected behavior

Comment: `mvn clean test` fails because of missing configuration files, and with junit test in Eclipse advices don't work. I'm using Eclipse IDE (Spring Tool Suite), but I launch the application with `mvn tomcat7:run`. In pom.xml there is neither aspectj library nor aspectj-weaver. I disabled AspectJ project's nature in Eclipse, then `mvn clean`ed and relaunched the application, but the behavior is the same. How can i disable AspectJ in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration uses `AspectJ` implementation.

It is configured with:  `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`. [(official documentation)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aspectj-support)

`proxy-target-class="true"` only says that CGLIB proxies will be used instead of Java Dynamic Proxies.

I guess you want to configure Spring AOP with CGLIB proxies. In that case the config string looks like:

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
...
</aop:config>
```

Comment: 6 years later... `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` does't enable compile-time weaving and just xml way of enabling the use of AspectJ annotations such as `@Aspect` (java-config way is `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`). Please see the documentation: `https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aspectj-support`. To enable compile-time weaving with AspectJ you need to use maven or gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to execute.

This is only true if your AOP is configured to work in proxy mode (which is default), but you configured **aspectj**, which handles both calls from outside the class, and self-invocations.

Comment: Are you sure? Where do I configured AspectJ? `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>` doesn't enable itself the aspectj weaving.